# Sorting 50+-digit numbers in array

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, sorting

I have array of strings containing 50+-digit numbers. I need to convert them to real-world integers and order them in asceding. It works when I have numbers with different size number of digits, but in this case where all numbers having same size number of digits it won't work:

```
string[] unsorted = {"324141241413213123123123132131451231231321363435243321413153412465745238454211425241244252423234234", "324141241413213123123123132131451231231321363435243321413153412465745238454211425241244252423234235"
        ,"324141241413213123123123132131451231231321363435243321413153412465745238454211425241244252423234200","324141241413213123123123132131451231231321363435243321413153412465745238454211425241244252423234100","324141241413213123123123132131451231231321363435243321413153412465745238454211425241244252423234731"};
var sorted = unsorted.OrderBy(s => double.Parse(s));
```

What's the best solution?

Comment: What test case does it not pass?

Comment: What kind of numbers, things that can be parsed to BigInteger?

Comment: Do you have a few examples of the numbers?

Comment: If you have a data type issue (as far as capacity for your numbers), you can pad the strings with leading zeros and sort them alphabetically.

Comment: @snow_FFFFFF: That would make the solution character-encoding (hence platform) dependent. Though I suppose that the alphabetic order of the characters [0-9] is preserved in all platforms... But still... That said, I'm not sure what the "C# standard" says about character-encoding. If it is an actual part of the standard, then I guess that my comment is irrelevant.

Comment: Too short, not enough details. Provide sample data and post expected vs actual results.

Comment: @harold I tried with BigInteger. Now it pass all test cases. Thank you :)

Comment: @barakmanos: If you want to know what the spec says, it's published on the internet in several formats. The spec says that C# strings are UTF-16-encoded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are working with *integers* you can parse them to `BigInteger` (both `double` and `decumal` are *too short* for such numbers, e.g. `Decimal.MaxValue == 79228162514264337593543950335` which is **29** digits only):

```
using System.Numerics;

...

string[] data = ...

var ordered = data
  .OrderBy(item => BigInteger.Parse(item))
  .ToArray(); // if you want materialization to array
```

If you're working with *non-negative integers* you can sort them by length and then lexicographically (no need in conversion):

```
string[] data = ...

var ordered = data
  .OrderBy(item => item.Length)
  .ThenBy(item => item)
  .ToArray(); // if you want materialization to array
```

The same approach for *any integers* (see Jason P Sallinger's comment) is also possible but not that elegant:

```
  var ordered = data
    .Where(item => item.StartsWith("-"))
    .OrderByDescending(item => item.Length)
    .ThenByDescending(item => item)
    .Concat(data
       .Where(item => !item.StartsWith("-"))
       .OrderBy(item => item.Length)
       .ThenBy(item => item))
    .ToArray();
```

Finally, please have a look at 
[Natural Sort Order in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp)

Comment: If you did have negative integers, you could split the set, do it in two passes, then merge the two arrays

Comment: @Jason P Sallinger: Thank you, I see! But the implementation of the idea will be combersome.

Comment: true.  At least it would be a step in the direction of fail-safe

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I tried with both solutions and both off them pass all test cases. Thank you :)

Comment: @gagro: you are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they're trimmed (no leading zeros) positive integers with no commas then:

```
unsorted.OrderBy(s => s.Length).ThenBy(s => s)
```

Would work because an untrimmed integer that is longer than another untrimmed number will be larger than it.

For negatives too:

```
unsorted.Order(s => s[0] != '-').ThenBy(s => s.Length).ThenBy(s => s)
```

Since booleans sort false before true and you want strings starting with `-` to come before those that don't.

If things are more complicated than that I'd use an `IEqualityComparer<string>` with a `Compare` method that:

1. If only one had `-` then it comes first.
2. Else if they both have `-` then trim off the `-`, call itself with the result and then negated that result.
3. Trim any thousands groupings (`,` in English-language use).
4. Get the length to the decimal separator (`.` in English-language use) in each or the full length if there is none. If different, shortest is smallest.
5. Ordinal string comparison.

Comment: Problem was I used double instead of BigInteger because double can't handle those big numbers. Changing double to BigInteger resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try this; (A Simple solution in linq) it works for both positive and negative integers numbers.

```
string[] array = { "2525213", "2525211", "-2525214" };

        var result = array.OrderBy(x => BigInteger.Parse(x));

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, that's basically copied and pasted from @Dmitry answer, and those are not 50+-digit numbers.